# Find the differential equation of $\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1-y^2}=c(x-y)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to find the differential equation of the following 
$$\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1-y^2}=c(x-y)$$
where $c$ is arbitrary constant.

I would like to show what progress I have made so far.

Let $x=\cos \theta$ and $y=\sin \theta$. Then the given equation becomes 
$\sin \theta +\cos \theta = c(\sin \theta -\cos \theta)$

$\Rightarrow c=\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}+\theta)$. Differentiating both sides we get 
$$0=\sec^2 (\frac{\pi}{4}+\theta)d\theta \,.$$

Now what ? Please show me the path. I don't know if this problem has been solved earlier or not. If solved before, kindly provide me the link.

P.S. Many many thanks to you all. Finally the solution I have found. This question is now solved completely.

Comment: @DeepSea How ? Please explain.

Comment: You're assuming that $x^2+y^2=1$. Why?

Comment: Choose $x=\cos u, y=\cos v$

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I don't know why I did that. I thought some sort of substitution will help to solve the problem but never thought like this as you asked. It was just an attempt which I failed.

Comment: @samjoe I tried that too but my computation become bigger and complicated.

Comment: I believe that you would like to find $dy/dx$. Then you can use the differentials like $df=f^{'}dx$ (assuming $f$ is a function of $x$). Then $d(\sqrt{1-x^2})$ becomes $\frac{-xdx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. I believe you can do the same for $\sqrt{1-y^2}$ by noting that $d(c(x-y))=cdx-cdy$. The rest is finding $dy/dx$.

Comment: @tempx Yes, but the trick is eliminating $c$ in order to arrive at an ODE satisfied by all the (implicitly) given functions. This can, of course, be done by solving the original equation for $c$, then substituting that into the equation for $y'$. But the resulting ODE may be quite messy.

Comment: I tried that process as @tempx suggested but the calculation became really bigger and complicated. There must be some twist to solve this

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I understood what you are saying. In that case what  we can do may be the following. We can express the given equation as $f(x,y)=\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1-y^2}}{(x-y)}=c$. Then again using the differential we obtain $df=f_xdx+f_ydy=dc=0$ where $f_x=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$. Although as you stated the solution may be messy.

Comment: @tempx  -- the "messiness" cancels out and you get from $df=0$ that $dy/dx=-f_x/f_y=\sqrt{(1-y^2)/(1-x^2)}$ which is not so bad.

Comment: @uniquesolution Thanks for providing the solution. I did not do it but as you stated the solution is not so messy, actually it seems it is quite normal.

Comment: @uniquesolution Thank you so much. My problem is solved. I have found the solution.

Comment: @Anjan3 Try $ \left(x+y+c^2 (x-y)\right) \,dx+ \left(x+y -c^2 (x-y)\right)\,dy=0$